# Compile issues with verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Can anyone see any blatant errors as to why this does not compile. I think the logic is correct for most of these operations. Its most likely syntax errors.
the only thing i can think of is the switch statement isn't written correctly as well as the add module. Each of the foury bit statements are connected to one of the modules below it. (bitwise not binary)

```
module _4bitALU(C , O , A , B , Switch);
  input[3:0] A ;
  input [3:0] B;
  input [3:0] Switch;
  output [3:0] O;
  output       C;

  case(Switch)
     4'B0000: notop(O , A);
     4'B0001: andop(O , A , B);
     4'B0010: orop(O , A , B);
     4'B0011: xorop(O , A , B);
     4'B1000: addop(C , O , A , B);
  endcase // case (Switch)
 endmodule // _4bitALU


module notop(O , A);
   input [3:0] A;
   output [3:0] O;
   assign O = ~A;
 endmodule // notop



module andop(O , A , B);
  input [3:0] A;
  input [3:0] B;
  output [3:0] O;
  assign O = (A & B);
endmodule // andop


module orop(O , A , B);
  input [3:0] A;
  input [3:0] B;
  output [3:0] O;
  assign O = (A | B);
endmodule // orop


 module xorop(O , A , B);
  input [3:0] A;
  input [3:0] B;
  output [3:0] O ;
  assign O = (A ^ B);
endmodule // xorop

 module addop(C , O , A , B);
   input [3:0] A;
   input [3:0] B;
   output [3:0] O;
   output       C;
   assign C1 = (A[0] & B[0]);
   assign C2 = ((A[1] & B[1]) | (A[1] & C1) | (B[1] & C1));
   assign C3 = ((A[2] & B[2]) | (A[2] & C2) | (B[2] & C2));
   assign C = ((A[3] & B[3]) | (A[3] & C3) | (B[3] & C3));
   assign O[0] = (A[0] ^ B[0]);
   assign O[1] = ((A[1] ^ B[1] ^ C1) | (A[1] & B[1] & C[1]));
   assign O[2] = ((A[2] ^ B[2] ^ C2) | (A[2] & B[2] & C[2]));
   assign O[3] = ((A[3] ^ B[3] ^ C3) | (A[3] & B[3] & C[3]));
   assign O[4] = ((A[4] ^ B[4] ^ C4) | (A[4] & B[4] & C[4]));

endmodule // addop
```

Comment: `notop`, `andop` etc. all the modules must be declared as functions and not modules. Also, `case` statement must be inside some always block. Like `always @(Switch)` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few problems in the `_4bitALU` module:

1. The `case` statement is not inside an `always` block.
2. You can't "call" other `module`s like you do in the `case` branches, instead you need to create *instances* of those modules and assign the `wire`s which connect to those instances within the `case` branches to the desired output(s).

These issues are rather basic Verilog, therefore I suggest you read up on how it is used (maybe [this tutorial](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/veritut.html) might help). Remember that you are (in most cases anyway) trying to describe the structure of hardware, not a software program that just gets executed.